# SFINAE on block of code

Tags: c++, scope, sfinae

In the code below, when SHOW_SFINAE_ON_TEMPLATED_ROUTINES_WORKS_AS_EXPECTED is defined, we have a successful demonstration of an instance of SFINAE on methods.

However, when TRY_SFINAE_ON_CODE_BLOCK is defined, substitution fails on a block of code while compiling for template being "struct no_am" -- and compilation errors out.  However, compiler knows at compile time that this block of code will not be executed when the template is "struct no_am" and so this failure ought not to be an error (or so I think!).

Please explain why compiler can apply SFINAE on a routine but is unable to apply SFINAE on a block of code.  Also, if there is a way to get compiler to apply SFINAE on a block of code, please show me how exactly.

```
// Compiled via command:
// x86_64_6.2.0_posix_seh_rt_v5_rev1/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -D_WIN64 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -O3 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ sfinae_on_code_block.cc -o sfinae.exe

#define SHOW_SFINAE_ON_TEMPLATED_ROUTINES_WORKS_AS_EXPECTED
//#define TRY_SFINAE_ON_CODE_BLOCK

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

template< typename T >
struct a_member_trait{
  static const bool exists   = false;
  static const bool is_float = false;
};

template< class T >
class see_sfinae_member_traits
{
    public:

      see_sfinae_member_traits( T t ) : the_t(t)
      {
      }

      T the_t;

#ifdef SHOW_SFINAE_ON_TEMPLATED_ROUTINES_WORKS_AS_EXPECTED
      void speak( const std::string& msg )
      {
          std::cout << msg << ":  ";
          speak_sfinae<T>();
      }

      template< class X >
      typename std::enable_if< a_member_trait<X>::exists   == true &&
                               a_member_trait<X>::is_float == true >::type
      speak_sfinae()
      {
          std::cout << "Has a_member, and that a_member is a float ["
                    << the_t.a_member
                    << "]"
                    << std::endl;
      }

      template< class X >
      typename std::enable_if< a_member_trait<X>::exists   == true &&
                               a_member_trait<X>::is_float == false >::type
      speak_sfinae()
      {
          std::cout << "Has a_member, and that a_member is NOT a float ["
                    << the_t.a_member
                    << "]"
                    << std::endl;
      }

      template< class X >
      typename std::enable_if< a_member_trait<X>::exists   == false &&
                               a_member_trait<X>::is_float == false >::type
      speak_sfinae()
      {
          std::cout << "Does NOT have a_member, float or otherwise"
                    << std::endl;
      }
#endif

#ifdef TRY_SFINAE_ON_CODE_BLOCK
      void tell( const std::string& msg )
      {
          std::cout << msg << ":  ";
          tell_all<T>();
      }

      template< class X >
      void tell_all()
      {
          std::cout << "from tell all:    ";

          if( a_member_trait<X>::exists == true && a_member_trait<X>::is_float == true )
          {
              std::cout << "Has a_member, and that a_member is a float ["
                        << the_t.a_member
                        << "]"
                        << std::endl;
          }

          if( a_member_trait<X>::exists == true && a_member_trait<X>::is_float == false )
          {
              std::cout << "Has a_member, and that a_member is NOT a float"
                        << the_t.a_member
                        << "]"
                        << std::endl;
          }

          if( a_member_trait<X>::exists == false && a_member_trait<X>::is_float == false )
          {
              std::cout << "Does NOT have a_member, float or otherwise"
                        << std::endl;
          }
      }
#endif

};

struct has_fam
{
    float a_member{ 1.1f };
};

struct has_iam
{
    int a_member{ 1 };
};

struct no_am
{
    int b_member{ 2 };
};

template<>
struct a_member_trait< has_fam >{
  static const bool exists   = true;
  static const bool is_float = true;
};

template<>
struct a_member_trait< has_iam >{
  static const bool exists   = true;
  static const bool is_float = false;
};


int main()
{
    has_fam   x_fam;
    has_iam   x_iam;
    no_am     x_noam;

    see_sfinae_member_traits< has_fam > ht_fam( x_fam );
    see_sfinae_member_traits< has_iam > ht_iam( x_iam );
    see_sfinae_member_traits< no_am   > ht_noam( x_noam );

#ifdef SHOW_SFINAE_ON_TEMPLATED_ROUTINES_WORKS_AS_EXPECTED
    ht_fam.speak( "hast_fam" );
    ht_iam.speak( "hast_iam" );
    ht_noam.speak( "not_am" );
#endif

#ifdef TRY_SFINAE_ON_CODE_BLOCK
    ht_fam.tell( "hast_fam" );
    ht_iam.tell( "hast_iam" );
    ht_noam.tell( "not_am" );
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One reason I could imagine to play a part in that is, that if that code block thing worked, you would not get the full debug version of your code. Even if a optimized release compile would remove that block of code inside the ``if()``, basically remove dead code, what would the non-optimized version do with it? It would of course create code for the block.  Basically you have dead code here and it is IMHO unrelated to SFINAE: ``if( false ) { ... }``.

Comment: What is this "SFINAE on code block" of which you speak? There ain't no such thing. The code in the block has to be well-formed, even if it's not executed. At least until [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) comes to a fine compiler near you.

Comment: Would like to accept @IgorTandetnik 's comment as the answer (cf. https://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/final-features-of-c17.html )